# Strange behaviour of request.POST in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm sending a POST request to a Django server through Postman. This is what the body of my request looks like

```
 POST /update/ HTTP/1.1
 Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----
 WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Postman-Token: 0764e56c-0fd8-fcce-5248-34f7d05f2748

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UploadDownloadSettings"

dssssss
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="settings"; 
filename="settings.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
```

When I try to access `request.POST['UploadDownloadSettings']`, the program says the key is not valid.

When I loop through the keys in `request.POST` I get a bunch of keys from the zip file and the key `name`.

According to the docs, this should parse out form-data. This seems like standard form data as far as I understand.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST

Am I misunderstanding the way the django post request works?

Output of request.POST

```
Key:
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition

Value:
form-data


Key:
name

Value:
"UploadDownloadSettings"


Key:
//actual filenames from the zip with their value

Value:
Blank
```

Output of `request.FILES`: blank map

Output of `request.content_type`: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: what's the output of `print(request.FILES)`?

Comment: can you show us the output of request.POST as well?

Comment: @OmarEinea I added parts of the output of request.POST. request.FILES is blank..

Comment: What is the value of `request.content_type`?

Comment: Updated above but it's application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Django is treating the request body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but it should be treating it as `multipart/form-data`. Looking [at the source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/http/request/#HttpRequest), I wonder if the problem is the `; boundary...`, which causes the string comparison to fail.